# Blazegraph Tinkerpop 3 Indexing

Tags: tinkerpop3, blazegraph

I am trying to learn about Blazegraph. At the moment I am puzzled how I can optimise simple lookups.

Suppose all my vertices have a property `id`, which is unique. This property is set by the user. Is there any way to speed up finding a vertex of a particular `id` while still sticking to the Tinkerpop APIs?

Is the search API defined [here](https://github.com/blazegraph/tinkerpop3) the only way?

My previous experience is in [TitanDB](http://titan.thinkaurelius.com/) and in Titan's case it's possible to define an index which the Tinkerpop APIs integrate with flawlessly. Is there any way to achieve the same results in Blazegraph without using the Search API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whether a mid-traversal V() uses an index or not, depends on a)
>   whether suitable index exists and b) if the particular graph system
>   provider implemented this functionality.

Gremlin (Tinkerpop) does not specify [how to set indexes](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graph-step) although the documentation presents things [like the following](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#credentials-dsl)

```
graph.createIndex("username",Vertex.class)
```

But may be reserved for the [ThinkerGraph implementation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#tinkergraph), as a matter of fact it says

> Each graph system will have different mechanism by which indices and
>   schemas are defined. TinkerPop3 does not require any conformance in
>   this area. In TinkerGraph, the only definitions are around indices.
>   With other graph systems, property value types, indices, edge labels,
>   etc. may be required to be defined a priori to adding data to the
>   graph.

There is an example [for Neo4J](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_indices)

> TinkerPop3 does not provide method interfaces for defining
>   schemas/indices for the underlying graph system. Thus, in order to
>   create indices, it is important to call the Neo4j API directly.

But the code is very specific for that plugin

```
graph.cypher("CREATE INDEX ON :person(name)")
```

Note that for BlazeGraph [the  search uses a built in full-text index](https://blazegraph.github.io/tinkerpop3/apidocs/com/blazegraph/gremlin/structure/BlazeGraph.html#search-java.lang.String-com.blazegraph.gremlin.structure.BlazeGraph.Match-)

Comment: Of course, you should double check if the index has the appropriate performance. For instance, if you had a numeric key,  the full text index would not be the perfect choice.